# Merge [ruby-1.9.1], [ruby-1.9.2], [ruby-1.9.3] into [ruby-1.9]?

Tags: support, retag-request, tag-synonyms

There are a few questions (compared to the total number of Ruby questions) tagged with

- [ruby-1.9.1](/questions/tagged/ruby-1.9.1) - 15
- [ruby-1.9.2](/questions/tagged/ruby-1.9.2) - 232
- [ruby-1.9.3](/questions/tagged/ruby-1.9.3) - 396

The excerpt for the tag [ruby-1.9](/questions/tagged/ruby-1.9) already suggests that the tag should be used for questions in the Ruby 1.9 branch.

I would propose to make these tags an alias of [ruby-1.9](/questions/tagged/ruby-1.9). There is really no need for one tag for every bugfix release.

---

This didn't happen in Ruby 2.0 just because there have been no 2.0.x releases. Thankfully, the majority of users don't know about patch level versions, or we will likely have one tag for each of them.

The differences between the 3 versions in the 1.9 (from a question POV) are not such relevant. Ruby 1.9.1 had a short life, it was replaced with Ruby 1.9.2. In fact, the number of questions reflects this and they are essentially related to Ruby or Rails in general. The use of 1.9.1 is just a secondary context detail.

Ruby 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 don't have relevant incompatibilities or notable features that would require a specific tag other than the 1.9 branch tag.

Answer (score 6):

In general, I think a tag shouldn't exist if it refers to a *minor* version of an application/framework/library.

[django](/questions/tagged/django) has only [django-1.3](/questions/tagged/django-1.3), [django-1.4](/questions/tagged/django-1.4), [django-1.5](/questions/tagged/django-1.5) as children and I'm fine with it.
Same for PHP: [php-5.2](/questions/tagged/php-5.2), [php-5.3](/questions/tagged/php-5.3)... there's a lot of examples on StackOverflow.

Minors versions add, *well*, minor changes in utils so they don't need a whole tag to determine if the problem is with ruby 1.9.2 or ruby 1.9.3 because the bug will probably exist on the whole 1.9 branch.

Comment: If I understood correctly, this is a **I agree** for the proposal.

Comment: Yep, that's it.